# Run different tasks differs only with one file

Tags: gruntjs

I have a complicated `.grunt` file which a lot of things. Among them is `concat`. It looks in the following way

```
concat: {
  libraries : {
    src : [many files],
    dest: 'libraries.js'
  },
  ... a lot of similar things,
  myCode : {
    src : [
      'config.js',               // this is the main problem
      ... a lot of files
    ],
    dest: 'myCode.js'
  },
}
```

So the main problem is that I have my preproduction environment and real environment. And I want different config to be included for each of them (let's say `config_dev.js` and `config_prod.js`).

The way I currently handle it is by creating different `code_` parts:

```
  myCode_prod : {
    src : [
      'config_prod.js',               // this is the main problem
      ... a lot of files
    ],
    dest: 'myCode.js'
  },
  myCode_dev : {
    src : [
      'config_dev.js',               // this is the main problem
      ... a lot of files
    ],
    dest: 'myCode.js'
  }
```

And then register 2 different tasks:

```
grunt.registerTask('default', [
    // my other tasks
    'concat:libraries',
    'concat:otherthings',
    'concat:myCode_prod'
]);
```

and

```
grunt.registerTask('default', [
    // my other tasks
    'concat:libraries',
    'concat:otherthings',
    'concat:myCode_dev'
]);
```

It works nice and correct, but the problem is that `myCode_dev` differs only in one file and a lot of other files (like 20 and they are adding/changing every week). And here is the problem: sometimes I forget to include/copy all of them and the problems starts.

So is there a way to do it in a different way?

**P.S.** I know that the title is bad, but can not find a better one. So please change it as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is to separate `dev` from `dist` early on. On [this project](https://github.com/dreamyguy/go/blob/master/Gruntfile.js) I have a similar approach that might prove useful. The main idea is to register two tasks and pick a default one (you'd still have to have a look on the tasks that contain `dev` and `dist` variations - in this case `uglify` and `compass`, to understand it fully):

```
// Compile production files
grunt.registerTask('dist', [
    'jshint',
    'jasmine',
    'uglify:dist',
    'compass:dist'
]);

// Compile developer friendly environment
grunt.registerTask('dev', [
    'jshint',
    'jasmine',
    'uglify:dev',
    'compass:dev'
]);

// Default task(s).
grunt.registerTask('default', 'dev');
```

The last line means that `dev` would run by default, when you run the command `grunt` by itself. If you'd like to to a build for production, you'd have to be specific, like: `grunt:dist`.

Note that this project is `grunt watch`-centric, which I believe is the best workflow. The `watch` task, if configured smartly, will only parse/compile certain files when the files being watched are changed. In that way `CSS` files are not compiled/concatenated/minified when changes are only done to `javascript` files, only `javascript` files. It's all there in that project, feel free to explore it. Cheers!